# Gradle sync failed debugImplementation 'com.amitshekhar.android:debug-db:1.0.6' sync failed

Tags: android, debugging, gradle, download, syn

debugImplementation 'com.amitshekhar.android:debug-db:1.0.6' can't sync in my project.

Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find com.amitshekhar.android:debug-db:1.0.6.
Searched in the following locations:

[text](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/amitshekhar/android/debug-db/1.0.6/debug-db-1.0.6.pom)

[text](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/amitshekhar/android/debug-db/1.0.6/debug-db-1.0.6.pom).How to solve it.Please!

*That is my Gradle*

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.parcelize'
    id 'com.google.devtools.ksp'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt'
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.myittaroostockinventorymanger'
    compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.example.myittaroostockinventorymanger'
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 34
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '17'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding(true)
    }

    buildscript {
        ext {
            agp_version = '8.1.1'
        }
        repositories {
            maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
            google()
            mavenCentral()
        }
        dependencies {

            def nav_version = "2.7.1"

            //for safeArgs
            classpath("androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version")


            classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:$agp_version"
//        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

            classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.9.10'


            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    def room_version = "2.5.2"
    def nav_version = "2.7.1"
    def arch_core_version = "2.2.0"

    //room database
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-rxjava2:$room_version"

    //rxjava
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.21"
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1'

    //navigation
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"

    debugImplementation 'com.amitshekhar.android:debug-db:1.0.6'

    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0"

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'

    //testing
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    testImplementation "org.mockito.kotlin:mockito-kotlin:$mockitoKotlinVersion"
    testImplementation "com.google.truth:truth:1.0.1"
    testImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:$arch_core_version"

    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1"
    androidTestImplementation "com.google.truth:truth:1.0.1"
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:$arch_core_version"


    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'com.nambimobile.widgets:expandable-fab:1.1.1'

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.9.0"

    kapt("androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version")
}
```

I tried many tiems.I can't sync.

Comment: I think the author have not yet migrated their lib to maven. Check this issue https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Android-Debug-Database/issues/216#issuecomment-1324728970